# Regular Expression- Find value before or after value

Tags: c#, regex

I have the values coming as [A].[B].[C].[D] and [X].[Y] I want to write regex  where one will give me value in [] which comes before D (in above example C) and one regex which returns value after [X] (for above example Y).

I am using C# , .net4.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`(?<=\[)\w(?=\]\.\[D\])`

`(?<=\[X\]\.\[)\w(?=\])`

*Example*

```
    [Test]
    public void TestC()
    {
        string input = "[A].[B].[C].[D].[X].[Y]";
        string actual = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\[)\w(?=\]\.\[D\])").Value;
        string expected = "C";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestY()
    {
        string input = "[A].[B].[C].[D].[X].[Y]";
        string actual = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\[X\]\.\[)\w(?=\])").Value;
        string expected = "Y";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`\[(.*?)\]\.\[D\]` - before D. Get group 1
`\[X\]\.\[(.*?)\]` - after X. Get group 1

Comment: Can't use (.*) because that will grab too much, need to exclude ']'.

Comment: it's in greedy case.   .*? is lazy and will grab until finds the first ] character.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[([^\]])\]\.\[C\]
```

and

```
\[X\]\.\[([^\]])\]
```

[consider reading up on regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 0):

First: \[([^\]])*)\]\.\[D\]

Second: \[X\]\.\[([^\]]*)\]